# Bounce mail blocked by Trend Micro Email Reputation Service

Tags: email, rbl

When I tryied to send an email, the following error appears:

```
200.123.99.139 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 Mail from 67.222.38.55 has been blocked by Trend Micro Email Reputation Service. 
Please see https://ers.trendmicro.com/reputations to get detailed information.
Giving up on 200.123.99.139.
```

I checked those IP en https://ers.trendmicro.com/reputations

- 200.123.99.139 is OK
- 67.222.38.55 is **Bad** in RBL

Apparently the owner of this bad IP is my **hosting service**.

¿Must I check the first or the second  IP? ¿What can I do with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation tracks.  The first IP is evidently the destination for your mail.  The second one is who they see as a sender.  Actually, the reverse could be true as well.  Compare your external IP to the two and see if one of them is on the same IP network.  If that doesn't work, compare registrar information using Reverse DNS and Whois (online network tools are awesome).  If all that fails, call your ISP for support.

Reverse DNS:

67.222.38.55 resolves to
"gproxy5-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com"

Top Level Domain: "unifiedlayer.com"

A Whois shows a lot more information.  You should look to see if your provider is the same as the owner of that address.  If they are, they can go through the process to be removed from the blackhole list.  Link was on the page you linked.

Comment: Then the hosting should request to be removed? It takes too long to be removed from a RBL?

Comment: I suspect a language barrier here.  If you are asking if you should change hosting companies because yours is on RBL, then I would suggest that it is up to you.  First, I would be sure that they are the culprit and not the destination.  If they are on RBL, you might ask them to give you a new IP that is not blacklisted.  If they legitimately did not know the address was blacklisted, they can work to get it off the RBL and they will probably help you.  If they cater to spammers as a big part of their clientele, they may not be helpful, in which case, personally, I would move in a heartbeat.

Comment: Hosting services said me: "There is an active server maintenance. The third party source RBL has been blocked. When you send back to back emails, the emails will go through. We recmend you to try after few hours once server issue gets fixed."

Comment: Sounds plausible.  If it works, you should enter the answer and mark it answered.

Comment: Hosting answer: "As you use shared IP, your IP will get blocked. It looks like one of sendmail server ips the server uses for sending mail has been blacklisted. We have admins working on getting that resolved and are working with the people that make those blacklists to be removed. We are working on it. No further action is required on your part. And also keep in mind that we have lots of sending proxies we use and that's just one of them, so it's likely you can just send again and it will work." Do you think I must believe them?